# Laravel channels not being triggered

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I'm implementing a Soketi solution with Pusher (I'm not using Echo). I'm able to send notifications to Private channels, however, I'm not able to validate if the user has access to the channel / endpoint, using the `channels.php`. It seems that `channels.php` is never triggered.

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('test.{id}', function ($user, $id) 
{
    \Log::debug('testing this endpoint'); // Never executed
    
    return false; // Also never executed, doesn't matter if true or false
});
```

**config/app.php**

```
'providers' => ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()->merge([
    \hisorange\BrowserDetect\ServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class, // <--- uncommented this line
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
])->toArray(),
```

**app/providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php**

```
class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Broadcast::routes();

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

**TestEvent.php**

```
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(public string $text)
    {
        //
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('test.3')
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'message';
    }
}
```

**Pusher JS configuration**

```
const pusher = new Pusher('app-key', 
{
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    authEndpoint: 'api/auth',
    auth:
    {
        headers:
        {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    }
});

const channel = pusher.subscribe('private-test.3');
channel.bind('message', function(message)
{
    console.log(message);
});
```

Testing the event:

```
broadcast(new TestEvent('Hello World!'));
```

---

What happens:

1. The user successfully connects to Pusher / Websockets
2. The event is sucessfully sent
3. The event is NOT validated under the endpoint `broadcast/channel/test.{id}`, meaning that the `channels.php` is never triggered

What am I missing?

**The Pusher Log**

```
Pusher : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
Pusher: ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"ws://127.0.0.1:6001/app/app-key?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.3.0&flash=false"}]
Pusher: ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 8035059900.2497835364"]
Pusher: ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"app-key:8623bcc00ba6c28dea66645316bd2eb2943aa5c8115f1cac7cede17e4994809a","channel":"private-test.3"}}]
Pusher: ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"private-test.3"}]
Pusher: ["No callbacks on private-test.3 for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]
Pusher: ["Event recd",{"event":"message","channel":"private-test.3","data":{"text":"Hello World!"}}]
my-js.js {text: 'Hello World!'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

It seems that I'm forced to use the endpoint `api/broadcasting/auth` in order to `channels.php` be called / executed.

On the Pusher JS configuration all I had to do was changing this line:

```
authEndpoint: 'api/auth',
```

to:

```
authEndpoint: 'api/broadcasting/auth',
```